# Restoring the default display context in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have found myself in cases where I accidentally run:

```
pd.option_context('display.max_columns', None, 
                  'display.max_rows', None, 
                  'display.width', None, 
                  'display.max_colwidth', 0)
```

**without** the `with` clause. Unfortunately, that changes my default printing options for all my `print` statements.

My question is: How can I restore the default `context`?

Calling `pd.option_context()` without arguments doesn't work, I get:

```
ValueError: Need to invoke asoption_context(pat, val, [(pat, val), ...)).
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `pd.reset_option` to reset one option or you can use a regex to reset more than one at the same time. In your case to reset all options starting with `display` you can do:

```
pd.reset_option('^display.', silent=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to retrieve the values currently set?

Comment: @user815423426, Yes, `pd.get_option('display.max_rows')` but the regex doesn't work in this case.

Comment: You can do `reset_option('all')` to reset all options.

Answer (score 4):

Use `reset_option('all')` to reset all options.

Credits: answer taken from the comment of @joris. I am posting this as the search-engine guided me here when I searched for how to reset all options, and comments are easy to miss.

Answer (score 0):

pd.reset_option('display.max_columns', 0) restores the display of columns to the default setting. Other options can be reset in a similar manner.